# How to fix the issue of Input has undefined rank in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to define a custom DensNet. But, I am getting a weird error and mot understand why. The code is as follows:

```
def densenet(input_shape, n_classes, filters = 32):
    
    #batch norm + relu + conv
    def bn_rl_conv(x,filters,kernel=1,strides=1):
        
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = ReLU()(x)
        x = Conv2D(filters, kernel, strides=strides,padding = 'same')(x)
        return x
    
    def dense_block(x, repetition):
        
        for _ in range(repetition):
            y = bn_rl_conv(x, 4*filters)
            y = bn_rl_conv(y, filters, 3)
            x = concatenate([y,x])
        return x
        
    def transition_layer(x):
        
        x = bn_rl_conv(x, K.int_shape(x)[-1] //2 )
        x = AvgPool2D(2, strides = 2, padding = 'same')(x)
        return x
    
    inp = Input (input_shape)
    x = Conv2D(64, 7, strides = 2, padding = 'same')(inp)
    x = MaxPool2D(3, strides = 2, padding = 'same')(x)
                        
    for repetition in [2,4,6,4]:
        
        d = dense_block(x, repetition)
        x = transition_layer(d)
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    
    output = Dense(n_classes, activation = 'softmax')(x)
    
    model = Model(inp, output)
    return model

input_shape = (1024,2,1)
num_classes = 24
model = densenet(input_shape,num_classes)
```

The error is stating the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/normalization/batch_normalization.py in build(self, input_shape)
    296     if not input_shape.ndims:
    297       raise ValueError(
--> 298           f'Input has undefined rank. Received: input_shape={input_shape}.')
    299     ndims = len(input_shape)
    300 

ValueError: Input has undefined rank. Received: input_shape=<unknown>.
```

Why am I getting this error? I have already indicated the input shape. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the code that is causing the error? I've tried reproducing the issue but it works fine on my end. Also, please add the imports, even those are important. You got `Input` like this right?  `from tensorflow.keras import Input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Input` layer incorrectly. You're passing `input_shape` to the `__call__()` method instead of the `shape` parameter.

Change:

```
inp = Input (input_shape)
```

To:

```
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
```